# Drupal 8 Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, bitbucket-pipelines

I am setting up a website with Drupal, the website is deployed on the live server through bitbucket pipelines. Normally when I browse to myurl.com/user it redirects me to myurl.com/user/login however now I get this error:

```
Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.
```

I have already set-up the "trusted_host_paterns" however this doesn't seem to fix the problem.
trusted host patterns:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
'^myurl\.com$',
```

);

Comment: Maybe you wanna show your `trusted_host_paterns` to add more context here.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody else comes here: It is also possible, that you have migrated a multi language site to a different server / localhost, and in your database are still the old redirect domains, that will now no longer work.

To fix this, you need to manually change the following value in the database. Go to dr_config and search for **language.negotiation**

In the cryptic blob, search have a look for something like

```
 {s:6:"source";s:6:"domain";
```

and change it to

```
 {s:6:"source";s:6:"path_prefix";
```

afterwards empty all cache_* tables (to force a reprocessing of the configuration) and there is a good chance it might work then.

Comment: Mate, you literally saved me hours of pain! Cheers

Comment: Great! I had to remove the acceptance part of some URL's after migration and this helped me a lot. (btw: the s:6 is the length of the following string , https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern seems OK to me. However there is what I'd check:

- Confirm using your browser that the redirect to `/user/login` happens to exactly `myurl.com` domain. Not `www.myurl.com` for example.
- Try clearing cache as well.
- Then looking through [this post](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-09-27/redirects-to-external-urls-are-not-allowed-by-default-use) on DO
- And then [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2612160). It's a D8 issue not fixed yet.

I remember having a similar issue on one of my websites during development on a local environment and the issue was really in the pattern.

Comment: The last link a comment on d.o. you posted helped. I had to add the .htaccess in public_html, also edit Drupal .htaccess in web/, and also add the lines to settings.php. Then it fully worked, including /user.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have this because of a multilingual site not finding the domains on localhost, put in settings.php:

```
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['en'] = 'my-en-url.localhost';
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['de'] = 'my-de-url.localhost';
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['es'] = 'my-es-url.localhost';
$config['language.negotiation']['url']['domains']['fr'] = 'my-fr-url.localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving your site from a subdirectory and you get this error on login paths then you need to add the below code to the settings.php

```
/**
 * To serve the site correctly from root URL when in a subdirectory
 */

if (isset($GLOBALS['request']) and
 '/SUB-DIRECTORY/WEB/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')) {
 $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

If you are not using composer you can add `/SUB-DIRECTORY/index.php` instead of `'/SUB-DIRECTORY/WEB/index.php'